# How to execute pure aql query?

Tags: go, aerospike, aql

I'm using [Official Aerospike Package](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go) for golang.

Is there any way to get list of all existing indexes this like?

> aql> show indexes

Also I haven't found any way to execute pure aql query.

How can I do this?

**Update:**
I'm looking for something similar to this but for aerospike (example from Rails)

`custom_query = "select * from users"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(custom_query)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AQL is an admin and data browsing tool. It's not really Aerospike's SQL, as Aerospike doesn't natively implement a query language. Instead, all the Aerospike clients give you an API to make direct get, put, scan, query calls, and those are procedural, not declarative like SQL (where you state how you want the result and the server figures out a query plan). Piyush mentioned the predicate filtering API which is fantastic and lets you create complex queries over scans and secondary-index queries.

Specifically to your question about getting all the indexes, that's the type of thing you should use the info command for. Aerospike allows you to get and set config parameters through it, and get a wide range of metrics, run microbenchmark, etc. Everything you need for admin and monitoring.

You can run [`sindex`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info#sindex) through the standalone [asinfo](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/asinfo) tool, or you can call it using the [info command](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/info.go) that any client provides.

```
asinfo -v "sindex"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly that what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2):

aql>show indexes 
is a valid aql command and should show you all the secondary indexes you currently have on the server.

aql runs the C api underneath. You can do pretty much everything with aql at a rudimnetary level.
Type: aql>help   it will throw all the aql commands at you, cut and paste!
aql also stores command history in a text file - so persists over sessions.
aql>run 'filepath/filename' is a handy way to store all aql commands in a text file and run them.

Re: aql query -- look at: select * from ns. where ... you can do equality and range queries provided you have pre-built the secondary indexes.

Aerospike ver 3.12+ introduced predicate filtering - ie ~complex queries - I don't think aql has been updated to run those yet.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! Looks like my question was not enough specific. Main issue is in aerospike library for golang. I can't find method in library, which will take query string and argument, execute it and return the result.

I'm looking for something similar to this (example from Rails)

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute( "select * from users")`

Comment: I doubt if you can do that. Aerospike does not 'understand' SQL or SQL like commands. AQL tokenizes and parses your strings and then converts them into Aerospike C function calls with arguments.  Hence AQL is limited in its capability compared to the client APIs. As far as I know, no Aerospike client is going to parse through a SQL like query string and then send the reformulated query to Aerospike server using the api format.

Comment: Yes I understand it, I provided SQL as example. For sure I don't expect from NoSQL database to "understand" and process SQL :D

Comment: Look at NewExecuteTask and statement struct. https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#Statement Also look at NewPredExp... Predicate filtering can be done on results of a secondary index query or a scan.